# How to match both multi line and single line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I’m trying to get my head around some Regex (using Python 2.7) and have hit a confusing snag. It’s to do with the (.*)   .  I know that dot matches everything except for new line unless you use the tag re.DOTALL. But when I do use the tag, it includes too much. Here is the code with a few variations and results that I’ve tried:

```
import re
from urllib2 import urlopen
webpage = urlopen('http://trev.id.au/testfiles/rgxtxt.php').read()

# find the instances of pattern in the file
findPatHTMLComment = re.findall('<!--(.*)-->',webpage) 
foundItems = len(findPatHTMLComment) # how many instances where found?
# Print results
print "Found " + str(foundItems) + " matches. They are: "
listIterator = []
listIterator[:]=range(0,foundItems)
for i in listIterator:
    print "HTML_Comment["+ str(i) +"]: |" + findPatHTMLComment[i] + "| END HTML Comment"
```

This results in finding 3 matches as it doesn't find the multi-line comment sections.

Using:

```
findPatHTMLComment = re.findall('<!--(.*)-->',webpage,re.DOTALL)
```

Finds a single match using the first  at the end of the document.

```
findPatHTMLComment = re.findall('<!--(.*)-->',webpage,re.MULTILINE)
```

Finds the same as the first one, only 3 out of the 5 comments that are in the file.

QUESTION: What is it that I should use in this instance as the regex?  Could you explain it for me and others too?

Appreciate any guidance you can provide. Thanks and have a nice day.

EDIT: Include sample data that was at link in code above (will be removing sample data from server soon):

```
<html>
<!--[if lt IE 9 ]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            function TopSearchIE9(input,inputBtn){
                var $topSearch=$(input);
                var $topSearchBtn=$(inputBtn);
                $topSearch.keydown(function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        $topSearchBtn.trigger("click");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            TopSearchIE9(".J-txt-focus1",".J-txt-focus1-btn");
            TopSearchIE9(".J-txt-focus2",".J-txt-focus2-btn");
        });
    </script> 
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 10 ]>
    <style>
        .new-header-search .hdSch-txt{ width: 225px;}
        .new-header-search .hdSch-del{width: 0px; padding: 5px 0px;}
        .new-header-search .hdSch-del.del{background:none; padding: }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
<body>
    <!-- This is a text file with a number of items to allow testing of some regex methods. It has no actual meaning -->
    <div head1>Item heading for first item</div>
    <!--By the way, this is a comment in a block of HTML text.-->
    <div itembody>We can jump over the moon if we are fast enough, but we really shouldn't try it cause we may get a blood nose. When we do try and succeed it feels quite good.</div>
    <div head1>Item heading for second item</div>
    <div itembody>If this is showing, its the second body within the itembody div tags for this file</div>
    <div head1>Item heading for the third item</div>
    <div itembody>
        Going to add another div tag 
        <div highlight>
            and closing div tag
        </div> 
        in this body to see how it handles that.
    </div>
    <!-- The above itembody data should 
        have it's own div and closing div tags -->
    <div head1>Item heading for the fourth item</div>
    <div itembody>
        <p><a href="mailto:fred@flinstone.com">email fred</a> or phone him on +63 493 3382 3329 when you are ready to try more regex stuff.</p>
        <p>You can also check with Barney by <a href="mailto:barney@rubble.com">emailing him</a> or phone him of +44 394 394 3992 if that is easier</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Thats all folks... -->
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post what you are trying to match exactly?

Comment: @JoeR I wanted to extract each instance of text between a <!-- and a --> tag. There should be 5 matches in the file. It's solved anyhow and learnt about greedy and non-greedy (.*) vs (.*?). Thanks, :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But when I do use the tag, it includes too much.

`*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. You need to follow the `*` operator with `?` for a non-greedy match which means "zero or more — preferably as few as possible".

```
re.findall('<!--(.*?)-->', webpage, re.DOTALL)
                   ↑
```

The `re.MULTILINE` flag is called multi-line because the anchors `^` and `$` operate on multiple lines when implemented, which in this case using the multi-line modifier is redundant.

On another note, I would consider using [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this task.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
```